# JUnit Spring MVC

Tags: java

I would like to ask for help regarding on how to perform unit testing on the following codes.  I developed it using Java Spring MVC framework.

```
@GetMapping("/top3Downtime/{type}/{date}")
 public List<Top3DowntimeChart> getTop3DowntimeByDate(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable 
 String date) 
         throws ParseException{

     if (type.equals(weekType)) {
            String weekStart = date.substring(0, 10);
            return top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByWeek(dateUtil.getParsedDate(weekStart));

        } else if (type.equals(monthType)) {
            String monthValue = date.substring(5, 7);
            String monthYear = date.substring(0, 4);    
            String fullStartDate = monthYear + "-" + monthValue + "-" + "01";

            return top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByMonth(dateUtil.getParsedDate(fullStartDate));

        } else if (type.equals(quarterType)) {
            String quarterValue = date.substring(0, 2);
            String quarterYear = date.substring(3, 7);

            return top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByQuarter(dateUtil.getFirstQuarterMonth(quarterValue, quarterYear));

        } else if (type.equals(yearType)) {
            String year = date.substring(0, 4);     
            beginningFormat = year + startDateOfYear;
            endingFormat = year + endDateOfYear;
            return top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByYear(dateUtil.getParsedDate(beginningFormat));

        } else {
            return top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByDate(dateUtil.getParsedDate(date));
        }
 }
```

So far, this is the codes I have made to JUnit test my program but I was not able to have it fully covered.  Errors were telling me I am missing some branches.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
@MockBean
private Top3DowntimeChart top3DowntimeChart;
@MockBean
private VarianceChart varianceChart;
@MockBean
private VarianceChartOnOffSite varianceChartOnOffSite;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
@Mock
private DateUtil dateUtil;
@Autowired
private Top3DowntimeRepository top3DowntimeRepository;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

List<Top3DowntimeChart> top3Downtime;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

    availabilityImpactChart = new AvailabilityImpactChart(91.90, "NCR", 20);
    availPerAtmRatingChart = new AvailPerAtmRatingChart("98", "97");
    consecutiveOfflineChart = new ConsecutiveOfflineChart("2020-01-01", 88);
    downtimeBreakdownChart = new DowntimeBreakdownChart("97", "85");
    downtimeChart = new DowntimeChart(95.95, "Category1", "2020-01-01");
    downtimeDistDailyChart = new DowntimeDistDailyChart("nameOfRegion", "atmOutOfService", "beginningOfDay", "cardReader", "cashDistributor", "cashHandler", "commandRejected", "communication", "connection", 
            "encryptor", "endOfDay", "purgedBin");
    downtimeDistOverallChart = new DowntimeDistOverallChart("date", "atmOutOfService", "beginningOfDay", "cardReader", "cashDistributor", "cashHandler", "commandRejected", "communication", 
            "connection", "encryptor", "endOfDay", "purgedBin");
    downtimeIntervTrendChart = new DowntimeIntervTrendChart("eventCategory", "2020-01-01", "00:00:00", 12.00f);
    eventCategory = new EventCategory("eventDescription", "eventCategoryString");
    heatMapChart = new HeatMapChart(97.12, "phRegion", 20, "2020-01-01");
    impactPerRegionChart = new ImpactPerRegionChart("locationName", 25);
    intervalChart = new IntervalChart("duration", "time", 15.15f);
    overallChart = new OverallChart("2020-01-01", 91.01, 8);
    overviewChart = new OverviewChart("region", "availabilityPercentage");
    overviewDowntime = new OverviewDowntime("eventDescription", 85.88);
    perRegionPerfChart = new PerRegionPerfChart("regionAcronym", 90.00);
    top3DowntimeChart = new Top3DowntimeChart("eventCategoryType", "column2", "column3");
    varianceChart = new VarianceChart("2020-01-01", 88.90);
    varianceChartOnOffSite = new VarianceChartOnOffSite("siteClass", 87.77, 85.00);

}

@Test
public void testGetTop3DowntimeByDate() throws Exception {  

    when(top3DowntimeChart.getEventCategoryType()).thenReturn("eventCategoryType");
    when(top3DowntimeChart.getColumn2()).thenReturn("column2");
    when(top3DowntimeChart.getColumn3()).thenReturn("column3");
    when(top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByDate(dateUtil.getParsedDate("2019-10-10"))).thenReturn(top3Downtime);
       //Top3DowntimeChart data = new Top3DowntimeChart("ATM Out of Service", "19.22", "23.15");
         //assertNotNull(data);
         this.mockMvc.perform(get("/top3Downtime/date/2019-10-10") .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
   .andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

}
@Test
public void failedGetTop3DowntimeByDate() throws Exception {  

    when(top3DowntimeChart.getEventCategoryType()).thenReturn("eventCategoryType");
    when(top3DowntimeChart.getColumn2()).thenReturn("column2");
    when(top3DowntimeChart.getColumn3()).thenReturn("column3");
       //Top3DowntimeChart data = new Top3DowntimeChart("ATM Out of Service", "19.22", "23.15");
         //assertNotNull(data);
         this.mockMvc.perform(get("/top3Downtime/date/") .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
   .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

}
```

Comment: What branches do you miss?

Comment: A lot of branches there... I would start by refactoring the code to be honest - making it easier to read, easier to see the branches, and much more easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: It tells me that I am missing 2 branches for every if statement block.  What my code does is when a correct URL was accessed it will then get a JSON data from a database.

Comment: `get("/top3Downtime/date/2019-10-10")` seems like this get might make the call. Is this supposed to be unit test? Or integration-ish? There's a mix and mangle between mocks, autowires...

Comment: Write test cases for each if-else-if statements by passing different type while calling rest endpoint, you should cover all branches created by using if-else-if.

Comment: Is the final `else` branch the only one covered?

Comment: base on the unit test code I've displayed, it will mock the url and will expect a HTTP status, one for ok and another for bad request.  I thought that I just needed to make one unit test for pass, and one for fail to cover all branches.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You also seem to call the method with the get, but on a mocked entity `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();` which would mean the whole thing is mocked. The only reason the last one works is because it doesn't match the path to anything mocked. But I might be wrong on how the MockMvcBuilder works.

Comment: not even the final else were excecuted, @dan

Comment: If you're not doing 'intergrationy' tests, then just mock the things you need in the class, Inject those mocks in the class, and call the methods with the params and do Unit testing. Not only check the status, what about the contents? Is the content altered in any way before returned, etc.

Comment: @Ronald - then this supports what I'm saying even more. You're mocking the whole thing up. So testing nothing.

Comment: @Vivek I have tried your suggestion, but it can't still cover the full code.  I included all kinds of type variable on the url to test all kinds of endpoint. Then, I also make a bad request url. What is the proper way to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean up the mock/autowired mess

   - Only mock things that are @autowired in the controller
   - Remove any other mocks unless necessary
   - Remove MockMvc if you want to achieve unit testing on this controller alone
2. Mock all the things this controller calls as externals

   - top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByWeek
   - top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByMonth
   - top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByQuarter
   - top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByYear
3. Inject Mocks using @InjectMocks into this controller

See below:

```
@InjectMocks 
ControllerNameHere controllerToTest;
```

4. Call the controller with different params in each of the test classes

Call the controller with injected mocks and validate the results

```
List<Top3DowntimeChart> result = controllerToTest.getTop3DowntimeByDate("date", "2019-10-10");  
assertEquals(EXPECTED_SIZE, result.size);
```

Comment: Thank you @MadaManu, out of 2 branch missing, it is now down to 1 branch missing.  My problem now is how am I going to call the interfaces of getTop3DowntimeChartByWeek, Month, Qtr, and Year which is inside my getTop3DowntimeByDate controller method.  But the final else has already passed.

Comment: your workaround has worked on my unit testing.  Thanks for the help.  But I am wondering why expected size has to be 0 because the actual is also 0.  Putting other value on expected size fails the test.  The endpoint returns 3 JSON objects. ``` List<Top3DowntimeChart> dateResult = controller.getTop3DowntimeByDate("date", "2019-10-10");  
  assertEquals(0, dateResult.size()); ```

Comment: Note, what I suggested is NOT a work around. It is the standard way of doing unit testing of spring applications. The size being 0 would mean that you didn't mock the `top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByDate` to return some Array with data in it.  You will need something like: `when(top3DowntimeRepository.getTop3DowntimeChartByDate(any())).thenReturn(somePredefinedList);`

Comment: Ok. Stand corrected. It did really helped me. Thanks, I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to testing such a method. One is to mock away everything use in the method-under-test; the other is to test your method as-is. For the first option:

1. Create a mock instance of `top3DowntimeRepository`
2. Create an instance of your controller injecting above mock
3. Call your method directly, there's no need to use mockMvc

For the second option

1. Create a mock instance of `top3DowntimeRepository` only if your test bed cannot supply it, or it slows down the test too much
2. Call your method via mockMvc URLs

In both cases:

- A parameterized test might be beneficial, read more on https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5
- The key parameter which dictates branch execution is the `type` parameter, but your current test only uses 'date'. Adjust that to 'week', 'quarter, 'month'